# EditorJS not usable even though clearly it is in my program

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tauri, editorjs

I am trying to integrate **EditorJS** with **Tauri + React**. I got the editor inside of my program but I cannot use any of the tools that EditorJS provides even though the editor is clearly in my program. I can interact with the editor (I am only able use the blue selecting feature) as shown in the picture but I cannot access any of the other features. Also the editor is only interactable in that small blue area. So if I click anywhere in the program I cannot in interact with it. So I would like to make the editor the right size and also usable.

[image]

Here is the code of the page:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Props } from './styles';
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';

const HomePage: React.FC<Props> = ({ pageName, visible }) => {
  const editorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const editor = new EditorJS({
        holder: editorRef.current,
        // Add your EditorJS configuration options here
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container className={`app-container-column ${visible ? '' : 'hide-page'}`}>
      <h1>Why can I do this?</h1>
      <div id="editorjs" ref={editorRef}></div>
      <h2>new</h2>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

To help you better understand the problem, I have created a CodeSandbox environment of the program that I have. Here is the link: [EditorJs Program CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/SisuKah/MathProject/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cliru8jn800ey3n6m69ssstpp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cliru6n4v000d3n6munm7zy8k%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cliru8jn800ey3n6m69ssstpp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cliru8jn800ey3n6m69ssstpp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clirueand00n93n6mltiruqcv%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522EMPTY_DEVTOOL%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cliru96nu00gz3n6m7z09fezj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FPagination%252Fpages%252FHome%252Findex.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clirueand00n93n6mltiruqcv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FPagination%252Fpages%252FHome%252Fstyles.ts%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clit0z4d0008j3n6noz3pvzhe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cliru6n4v000d3n6munm7zy8k%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clirukvv200773p6mnnr3dd20%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522EMPTY_DEVTOOL%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clit0yk47000b3n6nq3026dzr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cliru6n4v000d3n6munm7zy8k%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clit0yk47000b3n6nq3026dzr%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I kindly request you to take a look and provide any insights or suggestions you may have. Thank you in advance for your time and support.